# How to send collection to another view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is there anyway to send backbone collection to another view without listenTo methods, to send it like an array or something else.

Im doing the fetch in the initialize function and then putting the collection in my array is that bad?

```js
this.userModels = [];

this.collectionUser = new app.types.Users();
this.collectionUser.fetch();

this.userModels.push(this.collectionUser);
```

Im trying to send it like an array but on refreshing my web page sometimes im getting this

```js
this.options child {
  length: 15,
  models: Array[15],
  _byId: Object,
  _listenId: "l4",
  _events: Object…
}
```

and sometime getting with zero values

```js
this.options child {
  length: 0,
  models: Array[0],
  _byId: Object,
  _listenId: "l4",
  _events: Object…
}
```

So i wanna send my collection without listenTo method if it's possible.

First view:

```js
app.types.FirstView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.collectionUser = new app.types.Users();
    this.collectionUser.fetch();
  };

  sendCollection: function() {
    var secondView = new app.types.SecondView({
      collection: this.collectionUser
    });
  }
});
```

Second view:

```js
app.types.SecondView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.collection = options.collection;

    // so i want to get this.collectionUser here without listenTo 
    // method and without fetch here is that possible ? I said
    // sometimes i get it sometimes not when i refersh my web page 
    // when i render it first time.
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can send everything with js and use initialize for that view.
In your view you need to declare initialize function like this.

```
var someView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('some html file'),
    initialize: function(options){
        this.collection = options.collection
    },
    events: {
        'click .someclass': 'doSomthing',
        'click #someId': 'doSomthingElse'
    },
    doSomthing: function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var that = this;
         that.collection.fetch({
            success: function(){
                that.$('element').append(that.collection);
            }
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        var that = this;
        that.$el.html(that.template);
        return this;
    }
});
```

And when u make new instance of your view need pass your collection as argument.

```
this.collectionUser = new app.types.Users();
this.view = new someView({collection: this.collectionUser});
```

This is it

Comment: I did that but again im getting in that view length null `child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object}` .

Comment: In that case you just need to pass collection us argument and in your view call colection.fetch()

Comment: I will change answer now

Comment: When i refersh my web page sometimes im getting length 15 and thats the length of my collection and sometimes im getting zero when i refresh i don't know why im getting that.

Comment: you are geting that becous when your view renders your collectiion is not feched.

Comment: I have changed answer this way you will always get collection witch length is big than 0

Comment: But can i do it somehow with out that fetch because im rendering multiple tables on click so then every time when i wanna render new table it does the fetch and i need to wait then it's not user friendly. That's why im asking can i put in somehow in an array an then loop through the array it would be more faster then fetch.

Comment: Read answer i have changed it for your needs

Comment: Do i need put success for fetching it?

Comment: no. you can fetch your collection in initializer function and y\use it in your click function

Comment: You can post another question if you have so I will understand what you really need

Comment: Will do later, can't now, ios

Comment: `this.collection = options.collection` is unnecessary since it's the [default backbone behavior](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).

Comment: Yes, but it will be very difficult to explain to someone who does not have a lot experience

Comment: I will update my code soon so you can see what i want to do.

Comment: Ok but create new answer because we can get a lot downvotes:)

Comment: please console.log(this.collection) in your secondView and tell me the response